# NetCore 3.1 Project reference converted to package reference when packing

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core

I have netcore 3.1 Console application with a Package Reference and a Project Reference.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <PackageId>MyPackageId</PackageId>
    <Product>MyProduct</Product>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>true</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <AssemblyName>MyAssemblyName</AssemblyName>
    <Version>1.0.1</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Mono.Options" Version="6.6.0.161" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\src\MyUtilityProject.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
</Project>
```

I would expect the pack function to reference the compiled dll's from MyUtilityProject, but instead it looks up the version from MyUtilityProject.csproj and converts it into a package reference.

Here is the generated .nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2012/06/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>MyPackageId</id>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETCoreApp3.1">
        <dependency id="MyUtilityProject" version="2.13.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="Mono.Options" version="6.6.0.161" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src=".\MyProduct\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProduct.runtimeconfig.json" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1\MyProduct.runtimeconfig.json" />
    <file src=".\MyProduct\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\MyProduct.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp3.1\MyProduct.dll" />
  </files>
</package>
```

How do I convince the VS build job, that it should include the dll's and not reference the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to my problem was adding

```
<PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
```

to the project file.

I guess it was not quite clear from my question, that I was trying to build a tool, except for the fact that OutputType is exe.

This leads to the conclusion, that MicroSoft assumes that if you push a packet, all referenced projects are also pushed as packages.